# How to search for institutions/universities that have good contributions on a certain physics research topic?

Tags: education

For example, I am interested in the research related with "Quantum Hall Effects", and want to have a list of institutions/universities that have good contributions in this topic, with number of publications during the recent years. Any idea how? Is there any website provide such searching service? Google scholar, arXiv?

I tried [APS search](http://publish.aps.org/search) by searching "Quantum Hall Effects" in Abstract/Title. It shows all related papers. But now I just want to know the statistics of the institutional contributions.

Any idea how?

Comment: There is a quite related question on Academia SE: * http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/5300/1033 Quoting from [my answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/5302/1033) there: "**Look at affiliations in papers**. When I was looking for a PhD position, I systematically did an extensive literature survey. . . . The big advantage of this is that one will find mostly groups doing active research in the field." (For more details, see [this answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/5302/1033).)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Statistics on institutions should be taken with 14,000,000 grains of salt: some institutions have changed name over time (including many recently, e.g. in France many institutions were forking twenty years ago and are now merging back), and affiliation rules vary widely between authors (you'll see below huge contributions from state-wide agencies like “Russian academy of science” or “CNRS”, they are not the same as universities or labs). But, you can do it with many bibliographic search tools.

Here's how to do with *Web of Science*:

1. Make a regular search (here I chose “title”, but you can do something more complicated)
   [image]
2. On the results page, click on the “Analyze Results” link
   [image]
3. Choose your field of interest (here, organizations)
   [image]
4. Enjoy!
   [image]

Comment: Tokyo University at the top, now that's interesting!

Comment: Very nice. What is the difference between "Organization-Enhanced" and "Organization" at Web of Science? There are 10 campus of UC system, and many institutions of Russian Academy of Sciences, CNRS, and Max Planck Society, could we know more detailed list of specific institutions?

Answer (score 0):

This is not that good, but is the closest I can think of something like that.

Microsoft Academic is very good, and have tons of features like that.

[Here is a list of the most cited institutions on Machine Learning](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/RankList?entitytype=7&topDomainID=2&subDomainID=6&last=0&start=1&end=100)

[Here is a list of the most cited institutions in NeuroScience](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/RankList?entitytype=7&topdomainid=6&subdomainid=14&last=0)

However, I think it only works for preloaded topics.

Other problem is that MS database of indexed papers is rather small compared with Google's one.